# i dont understand this line ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);

Tags: android, android-layout

```
Button buttonRemove = addView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
                buttonRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        ((LinearLayout)addView.getParent()).removeView(addView);
                    }});
```

Comment: I'm also don't understand your question **`What is your question`**

Comment: It removing view(Linear view) on this button click.

Comment: I don't understand your question as well .Your title should explain the problem not demand for help . Edit it properly or it will close soon .

Comment: addView has wrong parameters passed how it can even compile

Comment: Tip: all the methods in this line are well documented. Read it and you will understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll evaluate this step-by-step.

First, this is evaluated:

```
addView.getParent()
```

There is some view called `addView`, and `getParent` returns the parent view of `addView` i.e. the view group that `addView` is in.

Then, we cast that to `LinearLayout`:

```
(LinearLayout)addView.getParent()
```

Whoever wrote this code seems to assert that the parent view of `addView` must be a linear layout.

Now, we take the result of everything we've evaluated and call `removeView(addView)`.

When you call `removeView` on a `ViewGroup`, that particular view in the view group will be removed i.e. disappear. Here, you want `addView` to disappear.

Basically what the code is doing is this:

> Get the parent of `addView`, cast it to a linear layout, and remove `addView` from it

In more abstract terms,

> Remove `addView` from its parent

Comment: Thanks, i understand it very well now

Answer (score 0):

On buttonRemove click you are removing the "addView" from the parent view.

So basically, button present on child-view is removing the child-view itself from the parent view.